# awk can't print array element

Tags: awk

Lets sat my file1 is:

```
A   S   
B   Q
```

file2 is:

```
B   2
```

I want to match $1 from file2 with $1 file1 and print file1 $2 && file2 $2, for the output like this:

```
Q   2
```

My `awk` solution is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1$2;next} $1 in a {print $2, a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

And it gives me only `Q` - it doesn't print array's second element.
How can I print array's element?

**Edit**

I updated my question as the answer that works for dummy example doesn't work with my actual data.

```
f1 
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1 
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1 
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1 

f2
ENSG00000236824.1   AAAAAAA
```

I want to match `f2 $1` with `f1 $3` and print `f1 $0`  plus `f2 $2`

I tried this answer `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} $3 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' f2 f1`,
but still not getting the output I want.

`awk` code above gets me only this:

```
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1 
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1 
chr2    47558199    ENSG00000236824.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. Just change the array index to $1 – that is the common element of both files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a {print $2, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

And no idea why you put $1$2 in the array, as you seem to need only $2.

**Update** according to the question edit.

You clearly put that “match `f2 $1` with `f1 $3`” (I wish every question to be so clear) so just write it in the code accordingly:

```
              f2 $1                             f1 $3
                |                                 |
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} $3 in a {print $0, a[$3]}' f2 f1
```

Comment: Can you please check updated question as answer doesn't seem to work with my actual data.

Comment: So we are saying:  
`a[$1]` - put in array `f2 $1`; if `f1 $3` is in array (that is `f2 $1`), then print. But 1) why do we need `=$2` ; 2) How do we make `f2 $2` encoded as `a[$3]`?

Comment: OK, when  we says `$3 in a` it puts `f2 $2` into that position, hence to print it we have to say "print position `$3`".

Comment: I think you got it. A generic advice: when confused, dump your variables' values. For example you can put something like this in your script `END{for(i in a)printf"a[ %s ] = %s\n",i,a[i]}` to list the indexes and values in array a. As with you current code $0 is already listed in the output just above `END`, should be clearly visible what to use as array index to get the corresponding values.